# Blackberry OS 6 Tab Bar / Toolbar

Tags: blackberry, tabs, toolbar, tabbar

I have been searching for hours, I have just started doing Blackberry OS 6 Development, new to it completely, it's a switch from IPhone.

I was wondering if someone could give me a deep in depth tutorial on how to create a multi view application with one global toolbar / tab bar.

Source code would be great so I can read through it and understand it better.

I created a basic app, but I am trying to add a global toolbar / tab bar to it, and am just struggling.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not "a deep in depth tutorial" :), however here is the info to start with:

- The API for [ToolbarManager](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/toolbar/ToolbarManager.html)
- [Example on ToolbarManager usage](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/18125/Toolbar_1247236_11.jsp)

Note the `ToolbarManager` is availble since OS 6. So for a previous OS you will need to create your custom `Manager` to hold the buttons and to place that manager into status section of the `MainScreen` (using the `MainScreen.setStatus(Field status)`).

Comment: Thanks i used setStauts to put the toolbar at the top of the screen, but can I have the title at the top and the toolbar right below it? i am trying to have a logo at the top (instead of text), and then the toolbar right below it.

Comment: Just a note - `setStatus()` sets a field to the BOTTOM of the screen. So could you please clarify the question?

Comment: Instead of using setStatus, I used setTitle to display the menu at the top of the screen, but now I am unsure how to get an icon above the menu.

Comment: Have you tried `setBanner()` ? Please try to ask one question at a time. I believe the current comments discussion is actually for another StackOverflow question.

Answer (score 0):

ToolBar is only available in OS 6.0, since I'm using 5.0+ as the base version.
I need to implement the Tab Bar manually.
Here's how I write it.

http://aliirawan-wen.blogspot.com/2011/05/implementing-tab-control-in-blackberry.html

In OS 6.0 you can simply using the Toolbar component, or doing with your own code